# how to retrieve ID after object store into database

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

I am using Java, spring, jpa for our application. I want to retrieve Id of insert row. Basically our ID is generated at the time of storing object into database.

```
RoleRequest role = new RoleRequest();

roleRequest.setUser(user);
roleRequest.setRole(role);
roleRequest.setRequestDate(new Date());
roleRequest.setStatusCode(Enum.PENDING);

Dao.persist(roleRequest);
```

So after storing this object, I need new generated id for this object, so that will perform some operation on it.

Answer (score 3):

```
Dao.persist(roleRequest);
```

After this line, the id should be set, so you can just do

```
Long id = roleRequest.getId();
```

(assuming `id` as id column and `Long` as id type)

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
oleRequest role = new RoleRequest();

roleRequest.setUser(user);
roleRequest.setRole(role);
roleRequest.setRequestDate(new Date());
roleRequest.setStatusCode(RoleRequestStatusEnum.PENDING);

Dao.persist(roleRequest);
int myId = roleRequest.getId();
```

You may need to do `EntityManager.flush()` after `EntityManager.persist()` (YMMV).